# Exploit open UPnP port

Tags: security, networking, upnp

Can anyone tell me if an open UPnP port on a network be exploited? If yes, How?
I am absolute beginner in security. I just happened to stumble on a host with open UPnP on the router. Want a proof of concept so that I can notify the company.

Comment: UPnP is enabled on routers because it offers actual functionality (usually https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol). Some people argue this is a security issue but these people typically don't explain how normal people should get ports open on their router instead when they need it... Abusing well implemented IGD requires there to be malware running inside your network and at that point open ports on your router may not be your main problem.

Comment: That said here are probably plenty of potential security issues in specific implementations as UPnP is a pretty complex protocol and the implementations on routers are almost certainly buggy and/or unmaintained.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen the port remains open at all times. Or at least all the times I have scaned the host so far. I fear that someone will exploit "StrangerCall" vulnerability (CVE-2020-12695). I did email them to close the port when not in use. But they may not take it seriously because I have not really tested it, neither am I capable of it at the time.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen also IGDP is for NAT and helps with port forwarding, right?? But UPnP is exposed, someone can possibly use it to mess with the NAT configuration. Is it possible?

Comment: You should ask on [security.se].

Comment: If your routers UPnP event subscription URL is reachable _from the internet_, then yes that would be a potentially serious security issue. If it's not reachable, then CallStranger can only be exploited by malware already running inside your network. Same goes for "messing with NAT".